# copying and pasting an event in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, fullcalendar

I have "implemented" a kind of a copy paste functionality in fullcalendar like so:

1. Use eventRender callback to bind right click on every event element  showing a contextual menu.
2. It copies the event
3. Binded every slot with a contextual menu to show the paste function
4. On menu-item-click i post data via ajax (new date and time) for the event, and return a new json of the event, to render back on calendar.

Why go to so much trouble when you could say that full calendar allready has an editable Event functionality. Because (unless I am mistaken) I wanted user to be able to copy an event, and move it to a different day (2 or three or 4 days later), where he sees an open slot. It works great (though I must do something with the timezones and time differences, cause the backend is in Django, using TIME_ZONE). But if i try to paste it in a different slot it just wont work. Here is a sample code (Please don't hate mye...)

event contextual-menu

```
eventRender: function (event, element){
    element.bind('contextmenu', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Right clicking') 
        showContextualMenu(event, element, e);
    });
}

function showContextualMenu(event,element, e){
    $("#contextual-menu").css({
        'position':'fixed',
        'top':e.clientY,
        'left':e.clientX
    }).fadeIn(500, function (){
        $(document).bind("click", function(){
            $('#contextual-menu').hide(500);
            $(document).off("click");
        });
        options = $("#contextual-menu ul").children();
        options.one('click', function (){
            console.log("Inside click");
            if ($(this).data('action')=== "move"){
                console.log("Inside if");
                alert("Copied event to move it");
                copiedEvent = event; //Global variable inside on $(document).ready()...note the best implementation I know, but had to pass the event everywhere
                paste = true; //paste is a variable telling us that there is an event wating to be pasted elswhere.
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I also binded the slots of the agenda with a contextual-menu so the user can right click on a slot and if there is an event to be copy in the "clipboard" to copy it.

```
//agenda-slots right click menu creation
var slots = $("table.fc-agenda-slots tbody").children();
slots.bind('contextmenu', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (paste===true){
        showSlotContextualMenu($(this),e);
    }
});
function showSlotContextualMenu(slot,e){
    $("#contextual-menu2 li" ).unbind('click');//If user only renders the menu but doesn't click i need to unbind the click method
    var hour = parseInt(((slot.first().text()).split(":"))[0]);//hour of the slot
    var minutes = parseInt(((slot.first().text()).split(":"))[1]);//minutes of the slot
    //start = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');//date in which i am currently (case i want to paste event on different date)
    //start.setHours(hour);
    start.setMinutes(minutes);
    //end = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate'); not necessary, the sever takes the duration of initial/copied event, and calculates the end time
    $("#contextual-menu2").css({
        'top':e.pageY,
        'left':e.pageX,
        'position':'absolute'
    }).fadeIn(500, function(){
        //user can click anywhere to close menu
        $(document).bind("click", function (){
            $("#contextual-menu2").hide(500);
            $(document).off("click"); 
        });
        $("#contextual-menu2 li").one("click", function(){
            //binding once every time contextual menu is shown...Dont think its the best way, please if you have advices, would love to hear them.
            if (confirm("This will move appointment with title: "+copiedEvent.title+ ". Do you want to proceed?")){
                alert("I will save your event");
                date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
                //ajax call to save event on success event will be placed in this slot and removed from the previous one
                $.ajax({
                    url:"/calendar/entry/move/",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{
                        id: copiedEvent.id,
                        start: copiedEvent.start.toGMTString(),
                        end: copiedEvent.end.toGMTString(),
                        color:copiedEvent.color,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken:$("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
                        year: date.getFullYear(),//new year
                        month:date.getMonth(), //new month
                        day:date.getDate(),  new date
                        hour:hour, //new hour (from slot)
                        minutes:minutes //new minutes(from slot)
                    },
                    success:function (data, status, jqXHR){
                        alert("Success, You will move "+data.title+" event");
                        event = copiedEvent;
                        event.start = data['start'];
                        event.end = data['end'];
                        console.log("about to save event"+ event.id+" "+event.start+" "+event.end);
                        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                            paste=false;                               
                            copiedEvent=null;

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

}
```

The problem is that when i change day e.g i copy an event on dec 18 and go to paste it in dec 20th the event won't render. The alert dialogs show me that they have the correct data (date etc) still the event won't render. I haven't saved the event in the database, i only return the event in json for testing but it works if i don't change day and paste it on the same day.Can't seem to find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I worked. But I changed the code a bit so that the copiedEvent is updated. So my server returns only the new start and end dates (django) like

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(start=start, end=end), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder), content_type="application/json")
```

and success function on ajax call

```
function (data, status, jqXHR){
    copiedEvent.start = data.start;
    copiedEvent.end = data.end;
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("upadateEvent", copiedEvent);
}
```

and now it works like a charm.